# Amortization table in c without loops

Tags: c, amortization

I have been tasked with creating a program that will generate an annual amortization schedule for a 30 year loan in C. The program accepts input of the loan amount and annual interest rate. From this I can easily calculate the monthly payment and annual payment.

The issue is that I am not allowed to use selection constructs, relational operators, logical operators, or techniques of repetition (loops), and I have no idea calculate how much of each annual payment goes towards paying off interest vs the principal without the use of a loop. I have attached an example output of what an example execution is supposed to look like.

[Example Execution of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ6Vs.png)

Comment: The only word you missed is "recursion". So that's probably what you're supposed to do.

Comment: wouldn't that require the use of a loop in order to terminate though?

Comment: Nope, you calculate one time period and then recursively call the function with the updated values, until the principal is zero. It's just a stupid way to avoid a loop by wasting space on the stack :)

Comment: Or you could unroll the loop into 360 blocks of code, one for each month. Using a C macro(s) would make this pretty easy: cut'n'paste the same line (invoking the macro) 359 times.